# Jenkins build fails after running Cucumber tests on Java heap space exception

Tags: maven, jenkins, cucumber

I get following exception when building using Jenkins. This exception raises after running Cucumber tests.

Can anyone tell the exact spot that fails on the java heap space?

Do you have any idea what can be done in order to solve it?

Some background: I had a java heap space during the Cucumber tests, after I increased the memory, Cucumber tests pass, but I get this java heap space right after.

Thanks,

Lior

```
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9(default-test)
[JENKINS] Recording test results
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Java heap space
Stack trace : 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.XMLString.toString(XMLString.java:185)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.XMLAttributesImpl.getValue(XMLAttributesImpl.java:537)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy.getValue(AbstractSAXParser.java:2319)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractElement.setAttributes(AbstractElement.java:543)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXContentHandler.addAttributes(SAXContentHandler.java:916)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXContentHandler.startElement(SAXContentHandler.java:249)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:377)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:264)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.parse(SuiteResult.java:112)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:227)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:163)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver.postExecute(SurefireArchiver.java:141)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordMojoEnded(Maven3Builder.java:421)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.mojoSucceeded(Maven3Builder.java:403)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.mojoSucceeded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:228)
channel stopped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the Jenkins settings and add the environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS` to `-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`. It looks like after your tests are finished it's trying to parse the results but the XML file is too large.

Comment: @LiorK you might also need to increase the heap size for Jenkins itself. What OS are you running it on?

Comment: I'm using Linux on Amazon ec2 server. Do you know how can I increase the heap size for Jenkins itself?

Comment: I'm playing with -Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize, it seems to be good direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your CI environment is like, but if you're running Jenkins as a Windows Service, you could also try increasing the heap size that's available to it.

To do this, locate the file at ${JENKINS_HOME}\jenkins.xml and update the command line arguments appropriately. (ie, change "-Xmx256m" to a larger value such as "-Xmx512m").

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to analyze the reason for the longer output from the cucumber. 
In my case it was same stack trace which was reported by the cucumber for too many tests.

Comment: A bunch of tests failing for the same reason.